# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/window/OnBackInvokedCallback for ComponentActivity

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, jacoco, robolectric, androidx-test

Running Jacoco results in following error message:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/window/OnBackInvokedCallback
    at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.<init>(ComponentActivity.java:150)
    at com.example.sheets.BottomSheetServiceTest$TestActivity.<init>(BottomSheetServiceTest.kt:28)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at org.robolectric.util.ReflectionHelpers.callConstructor(ReflectionHelpers.java:422)
    at org.robolectric.Robolectric.buildActivity(Robolectric.java:108)
    at org.robolectric.android.internal.RoboMonitoringInstrumentation.startActivitySyncInternal(RoboMonitoringInstrumentation.java:103)
    at org.robolectric.android.internal.LocalActivityInvoker.startActivity(LocalActivityInvoker.java:33)
    at org.robolectric.android.internal.LocalActivityInvoker.startActivity(LocalActivityInvoker.java:38)
    at androidx.test.core.app.ActivityScenario.launchInternal(ActivityScenario.java:266)
    at androidx.test.core.app.ActivityScenario.launch(ActivityScenario.java:196)
    at androidx.test.ext.junit.rules.ActivityScenarioRule.lambda$new$0$ActivityScenarioRule(ActivityScenarioRule.java:70)
    at androidx.test.ext.junit.rules.ActivityScenarioRule$$Lambda$0.get(ActivityScenarioRule.java:70)
    at androidx.test.ext.junit.rules.ActivityScenarioRule.before(ActivityScenarioRule.java:103)
    at org.junit.rules.ExternalResource$1.evaluate(ExternalResource.java:50)
    at androidx.compose.ui.test.junit4.AndroidComposeTestRule$apply$1$evaluate$1.invoke(AndroidComposeTestRule.android.kt:148)
    at androidx.compose.ui.test.junit4.AndroidComposeTestRule$apply$1$evaluate$1.invoke(AndroidComposeTestRule.android.kt:147)
    at androidx.compose.ui.test.AndroidComposeUiTestEnvironment$AndroidComposeUiTestImpl.withDisposableContent(ComposeUiTest.android.kt:476)
    at androidx.compose.ui.test.AndroidComposeUiTestEnvironment$runTest$1$1$1$1$1$1$1.invoke(ComposeUiTest.android.kt:294)
    at androidx.compose.ui.test.AndroidComposeUiTestEnvironment.withTextInputService(ComposeUiTest.android.kt:360)
    at androidx.compose.ui.test.AndroidComposeUiTestEnvironment.access$withTextInputService(ComposeUiTest.android.kt:217)
    at androidx.compose.ui.test.AndroidComposeUiTestEnvironment$runTest$1$1$1$1$1$1.invoke(ComposeUiTest.android.kt:293)
    at androidx.compose.ui.test.AndroidComposeUiTestEnvironment.withComposeIdlingResource(ComposeUiTest.android.kt:347)
    at androidx.compose.ui.test.AndroidComposeUiTestEnvironment.access$withComposeIdlingResource(ComposeUiTest.android.kt:217)
    at androidx.compose.ui.test.AndroidComposeUiTestEnvironment$runTest$1$1$1$1$1.invoke(ComposeUiTest.android.kt:292)
    at androidx.compose.ui.test.AndroidComposeUiTestEnvironment.withWindowRecomposer(ComposeUiTest.android.kt:321)
    at androidx.compose.ui.test.AndroidComposeUiTestEnvironment.access$withWindowRecomposer(ComposeUiTest.android.kt:217)
    at androidx.compose.ui.test.AndroidComposeUiTestEnvironment$runTest$1$1$1$1.invoke(ComposeUiTest.android.kt:291)
    at androidx.compose.ui.test.AndroidComposeUiTestEnvironment.withTestCoroutines(ComposeUiTest.android.kt:334)
    at androidx.compose.ui.test.AndroidComposeUiTestEnvironment.access$withTestCoroutines(ComposeUiTest.android.kt:217)
    at androidx.compose.ui.test.AndroidComposeUiTestEnvironment$runTest$1$1$1.invoke(ComposeUiTest.android.kt:290)
    at androidx.compose.ui.test.junit4.IdlingStrategy.withStrategy(IdlingStrategy.android.kt:52)
    at androidx.compose.ui.test.AndroidComposeUiTestEnvironment$runTest$1$1.invoke(ComposeUiTest.android.kt:289)
    at androidx.compose.ui.test.junit4.IdlingResourceRegistry.withRegistry(IdlingResourceRegistry.jvm.kt:157)
    at androidx.compose.ui.test.AndroidComposeUiTestEnvironment$runTest$1.invoke(ComposeUiTest.android.kt:288)
    at androidx.compose.ui.test.junit4.ComposeRootRegistry.withRegistry(ComposeRootRegistry.android.kt:146)
    at androidx.compose.ui.test.AndroidComposeUiTestEnvironment.runTest(ComposeUiTest.android.kt:287)
    at androidx.compose.ui.test.junit4.AndroidComposeTestRule$apply$1.evaluate(AndroidComposeTestRule.android.kt:147)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$HelperTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:591)
    at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner$2.lambda$evaluate$0(SandboxTestRunner.java:274)
    at org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.Sandbox.lambda$runOnMainThread$0(Sandbox.java:88)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
```

Whereas my BottomSheetServiceTest including TestActivity looks similar to:

```
class BottomSheetServiceTest {
    class TestActivity: ComponentActivity() {
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContent {
                //..
            }
        }
    }
    @get:Rule
    val rule = createAndroidComposeRule<TestActivity>()
 }
```

As you can see Roboelectric is used also for tests. I tried to set compose activtiy version back to 1.5.0-beta01 but did not help.

```
compileSdkVersion = 32
buildToolsVersion = "31.0.0"
targetSdkVersion(31)
```

Comment: Are using the OnBackInvokedCallback API somewhere?